# Kafka's ZookeeperConsumerConnector.createMessageStreams never returns

Tags: clojure, apache-kafka, clj-kafka

I'm trying to retrieve data from my Kafka 0.8.1 cluster. I have brought into existence an instance of `ZookeeperConsumerConnector` and then attempt to call `createMessageStreams` on it. However, no matter what I do, it seems `createMessageStreams` just hangs and never returns, even if it is the only thing I have done with Kafka.

Reading mailing lists it seems this can sometimes happen for a few reasons, but as far as I can tell I haven't done any of those things.

Further, I'll point out that I'm actually doing this in Clojure using clj-kafka, but I suspect clj-kafka is not the issue because I have the problem even if I run this code:

```
(.createMessageStreams
  (clj-kafka.consumer.zk/consumer {"zookeeper.connect" "127.0.0.1:2181"
                                   "group.id" "my.consumer"
                                   "auto.offset.reset" "smallest"
                                   "auto.commit.enable" "false"})
  {"mytopic" (int 1)})
```

And [`clj-kafka.consumer.zk/consumer`](https://github.com/pingles/clj-kafka/blob/master/src/clj_kafka/consumer/zk.clj) just uses `Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector` to create a `ZookeeperConsumerConnector` without doing anything too fancy.

Also, there are definitely messages in "mytopic" because from the command line I can run the following and get back everything I've already sent to the topic:

```
% kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 127.0.0.1:2181 --topic mytopic --from-beginning
```

So it's also not that the topic is empty.

Feeling stumped at this point. Ideas?

**ETA:** By "hang" I guess what I really mean is that it seems to spin up a thread and then stay stuck in it never doing anything. If I run this code from the REPL I can get out of it by hitting control-c and then I get this error:

```
IllegalMonitorStateException   java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease (ReentrantLock.java:155)
```

Comment: I still have not solved this problem, but I've temporarily switched to RabbitMQ, which I seem to have working and should hold me for a while. Solution still sought, though, because I will eventually need to handle more volume than RabbitMQ can support.

Comment: What happens if you use some random new group.id instead of "my.consumer" ? The offset for "my.consumer" might already have been committed to ZK.

Comment: @sandris I don't remember if I tried that specifically, but I'm fairly certain I saw this issue even with a fresh ZK and Kafka that was being used for the first time, so anything I supplied as group.id should have been new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing the same issue with the same exception when interrupting the REPL. The reason it hangs is due to the lazy-iterate function in the consumer.zk namespace. The queue from which messages are read is a LinkedBlockingQueue and the call to .hasNext in the lazy-iterate function calls .take on this queue. This creates a read lock on the queue and will block and wait until something is available to take off the queue. This means that the lazy-iterate function will never actually return. lazy-iterate is called by the 'messages' function and if you don't do something like

```
(take 2 (messages "mytopic" some-consumer))
```

then the messages function will never return and hang indefinitely. It's my opinion that this is a bug (or design flaw) in clj-kafka. To illustrate that this is indeed what's happening, try setting "consumer.timeout.ms" "0" in your consumer config. It will throw a TimeoutExpection and return control to the REPL.

This further creates a problem with the 'with-resource' macro. The macro takes a binding to a consumer, a shutdown function, and a body; it calls the body and then the shutdown fn. If inside the body, you make a call to 'messages', the body will never return and thus the shutdown function will never be called. The messages function WOULD return if shutdown was called, because shutdown puts a message on the queue that signals the consumer to clean up its resources and threads in preparation for GC. This macro puts the application into a state where the only way to get out of the main loop is to kill the application (or a thread calling it) itself. The library certainly has a ways to go before it's ready for a production environment.